# Nuxt Showing 2 Instances of Vue Running

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Why do I have 2 instances of Vue running in Nuxt?

This happens in both Nuxt apps I'm working on.

[image]

I saw somewhere here they recommended nuking and reinstalling node modules, tried that with no change.

I also disabled my plugins prior to taking this snap, there is no place in the app that's calling Vue other than the Nuxt internals.

How do I make this stop?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the `modern`build?

Comment: I don't know what you mean? I used the `npx create-nuxt-app` method to create the apps.

Comment: Did you do any other configuration, if yes please share it. You can also link a Github repo but IMO, here it is just that you're loading both the commonJS and modern (ES) build at the same time as explained here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-modern/ What is your OS/browser?

Comment: Chrome on Mac. No build config in nuxt.config other than target and having ssr turned off.

Comment: Hm, I do have the same behavior on my app but nothing on a freshly created one. Mind sharing your `package.json` and `nuxt.config.js` to try to see what we have in common?

Comment: I've discovered that this is being caused by `@nuxtjs/auth-next` module. With it enabled it calls the vue common js file creating a whole new instance of vue. Does anyone know if there's a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: This module is pretty beta still, so I'm not sure that we can do much besides maybe trying the latest version or waiting for it to be stable.

Comment: Beta? `nuxt/auth` was released years ago. But no matter, this seems to be normal behavior running on localhost under `dev` it doesn't occur in production or when rendered to static so it seems like it's not really an issue.

Comment: The v5 is pretty early on and is not 100% bulletproof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't happen in production, or when running from an actual domain ie: on Valet. Nor is there any effect when producing static pages, so this really isn't an issue.

Once I moved it to a domain, it stopped even in `dev` so no reason to pursue this any further.